# Why does a subclass have access to a private member of the superclass with inner classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes, access-modifiers

```
    public class Main {
    static class Article {
        // Price in Article, private!
        private float price;

        Article(float price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    }

    static class Milk extends Article {

        Milk(float price) {
            super(price);
            //Has access to private price
            System.out.println(super.price);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main.Milk(1.5f);

    }
}
```

In this example, the subclass has access to a private member via super.price 
What is the meaning of [access specifiers in inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)?

Comment: "What is the meaning of access specifiers in inner classes?"  They still control access from other code. There is no need to hide it from code in the same enclosing class. One of the main motivations for grouping code into nested classes is to allow them to be tightly coupled (without leaking these things out into package scope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JLS 6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared `private`, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level type (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

A nested class can thus access private members of its top-level class and vice versa. For all practical purposes, private members are accessible exactly within the current `.java` file.

Comment: `A nested class can thus access private members of its top-level class and vice versa` - that's not what happens in the OP's code, though. The private member belongs to one nested class and it is accessed from another nested class. That said, this JLS quote still applies.